# How well does Internet Explorer work with NodeJS, Javascript and HTML/CSS nowadays?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm unsure whether to create a desktop app via Electron or create a WebApp instead. My customers are to 70% IE (i believe mostly older versions) users and I don't want the app to run slow, crash or not support features and animations. So knowing how IE does nowadays would help me with this decision greatly.

Comment: IE is deprecated. You want to know about edge, and still that has nothing to do with NodeJS since that is a server application, where the browser is for front end development. Comparing the two pieces of software is irrelevant.

Comment: If you would like to know about basic function compatibility, I suggest visiting https://caniuse.com

Comment: @muka.gergely Thanks! Just what I needed!

Comment: Quite correct and up to date source of info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE does not support a lot of new functionality. But if you write your pages correctly that is not a problem. It can be difficult and expensive to get things to work in up-to-date browsers, mobile browsers and IE, but it can be done.

Electron is great since it provides the same browser interface for everyone. But Electron Apps *can* become very bloated and large. If you want to only use the latest HTML, CSS and JavaScript then Electron is much simpler to use then a Web App. But using Electron means that your customers will *not* be able to get at your code from their mobile devises.

Comment: Mobile devices will have a separate app, so that's not an issue. I will use Electron in that case, don't think it's then worth bothering with each browser and especially not IE issues. Thanks for the answer!